# add_action taking an array with the 2nd argument?

Tags: php, actions

I was going through some source code of Astra theme and found these lines in `theme/astra/inc/class-astra-loop.php`:

```
class Astra_Loop {

    .....
    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'astra_content_loop', array( $this, 'loop_markup' ) );

 .....
```

Shouldn't the 2nd argument be a function? Apparently here the 2nd argument is an array. I checked it with `json_encode(array( $this, 'loop_markup' ))`, it outputs `[{},"loop_markup"]`. So how is this working?

Comment: did my answer solve your question? If it did can you mark it as the accepted answer using the tick under the voting controls? And can you go back through the questions you asked and check the answers and mark correct answers as correct? I notice you have not accepted any answers on the questions you've asked, but you also haven't commented on them if you had issues or they were incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't the 2nd argument be a function?

The second argument should be a value of type `callable`. `callable`s are a fundamental type in PHP.

E.g. these are some valid callables:

| Value | Equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| `'test'` | `test()` |
| `[ $obj, 'test' ]` | `$obj->test()` |
| `[ 'foo', 'bar' ]` | `foo::bar()` |
| `function() {...}` or closure | `$foo = function(){...}; $foo();` |

And so on, [see the official docs at php.net for more details.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)